# Setting up traffic router (proxy ?) for production

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid

I am running a production server and my web application is running at port 8099. so if front end wants to access any backend endpoint, they make a call to this url:

```
http://production.server.com:8099/mainserver/some/get?xxxxxxx
```

I need to setup production.server.com:8099 to something like api.production-server.com, which will point to production.server.com:8099. What's the best approach to this? This is for ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Nginx

```
server {
     server_name  https://api.production-server.com;
     location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8099; }
}
```

see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034125/1992247

Comment: production.server.com should be replaced with api.production-server.com in my example. It worked.

Comment: Edited to match the correct server name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is a apache server.

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </proxy>

    ServerName https://production.server.com
    ProxyPass https://api.production-server.com   https://production.server.com:8099
    ProxyPassReverse https://api.production-server.com   https://production.server.com:8099
```

Comment: We use nginx here. What's the equivalent in nginx for what you suggested?